# What is the correct syntax to access a field value running a JavaScript file for mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, syntax, field, environment

I am running this command in my terminal
    `$mongo <database> -u user -p pw update.js`

The update.js includes this code

```
var cursor = db.resources.find({
    user: "dummy0"
});
print('cursor:', cursor);
var oldMatter = cursor.values.green;
```

My terminal output and the error I get is as follows
`cursor: DBQuery: scrounge.resources -> { "user" : "dummy0" }
E QUERY    TypeError: Cannot read property 'green' of undefined`

What is the environment / API / driver I am using?
What is the correct Syntax to access the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried analyzing the cursor returned? `db.resources.find` will returns an object wrapped in an iterable cursor/array, so you can't just go about accessing properties of your object on the `cursor` variable - `cursor.values.green` will not work.

Try using `findOne` instead like so:

```
var obj = db.resources.findOne({
    user: "dummy0"
});
```

This returns an object not wrapped as an iterable cursor/array so assuming it finds an object, you should be able to do

```
obj.values.green;
```

Comment: findOne solved the problem so far since it returns one object. No idea how to analyse the cursor though. I tried to get the structure by printing the cursor to the terminal.